# Using Newton's Method to estimate a zero between a specific set of values?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

One of the problems in my Calculus books states, "Use Newton's method to estimate the zero between  $x=1$ and $x=2$ for the function $f(x)=X^3+2x-4$. Find the root to four decimal places."

Can someone help walk me through how to work this type of problem?

Comment: Do you know what "Newton's method" is?  This problem clearly assumes that you do!

Comment: Yes, it clearly does, and no, I do not. Our class worked through 1 example and that was "Find the  Positive fourth root of 2 by  solving the equation $x^4-2=0$. This one is different  than what I've done before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Newton Method recurrence for solving $f(x)=0$ is
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}.\tag{1}$$ Here $f(x)=x^3+2x-4$ and $f'(x)=3x^2+2$.

Note that $f(1)=-1$ and $f(2)=8$. So it looks as if the root is closer to $1$ than to $2$. It is not unreasonable to make initial estimate $x_0=1$.
We now calculate $x_1$. By (1), we have
$$x_1=x_0-\frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)}=1+\frac{1}{5}.$$
Thus $x_1=1.2$. Repeat.

Run through a few iterations of the method. The only remaining issue is when to stop. Maybe when you do the calculations you will figure out when to stop. If you have difficulty, please report on your calculations and I will help you resolve this.

Comment: Ok, so going all the way out to the fourth root of x, I get $1.179509025$. in order I found:  $[x2]=1.179746835, [x3]=1.179509057, [x4]=1.179509025$. Since I've found [x4], what then is my actual answer to this question? $1.1795$?

Comment: Good work.  Practically, once you have found two consecutive estimates that agree to $4$ decimal places, you can stop. If you are feeling hypercautious, you may check whether $f(1.1795)\lt 0$ and $f(1.17955)\gt 0$. That will *prove* that your estimate is close enough. When things are going well, which is not always the case, and you start not  far from the root, the Newton Method gives fantastic accuracy quickly. Your $x_3$ is already good to $7$ places, and your $x_4$, if the calculation is carried out on a device that does high accuracy arithmetic, is probably correct to $14$ or so places!

Comment: In this case I chose $1$ as the initial estimate, for the reasons described, and because it is a nice number. It would have been better to "guess" somewhere around $1.1$. A good initial estimate can have a nice payoff. A bad initial estimate can lead to excessive computation, or even disaster (non-convergence)

Answer (score 0):

You atart with 2 as a rough initial approximation of a root. Now geometrically speaking the method asks you to draw a tangent to the curve $y=f(x)$, at the point with co-ordinates $\big(2,f(2)\big)$ and see where this tangent line cuts the $x$-axis, call that point $(x_1,0)$. This $x_1$ would be closer to the root than the initial value $2$. Now repeat the same procedure with $x_1$, that is draw the tangent to the same curve at $\big(x_1, f(x_1)\big)$ and so on.

The caclulation needs the equation of the tangent line: we know one point $(2,f(2))$. If the s0lpe of the tangent $m$ is known then the equation can be written as $y-f(2) = m(x-2)$. But calclusus says the the slope of the tangent line is the derivative: i.e., $m=f'(2)$. In this case as $f'(x)=3x^2+2$ we get $m=14$. So the tangent is the line given by $y-8=14(x-2)$.  Substitute $y=0$ in that equation. and get $x_1=\frac8{14}+2=  \frac{19}7$ as a better approximation. Starting with $2$ we have now arrived at $1.571428$.
Now keep repeating the procedure until the new number aggrees with the previous number in 4 decimal places.